# Checkbox required on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Was trying to find something how to make checkboxes required.
Like `required="required"` as below this is how I generate my checkboxes 
I would appreciate any help on how to do so. My system requires at least one checkbox to be checked. also would like if it won't be a popup. `alert('');`

```
<?php 
                $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tourism_type order by type_name ");
                $i=1;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="type" 
                        value='.$row['type_id'].' id='.$row['type_id'].'>'.'
                            <label for='.$row['type_id'].'
                            class="fil_lab">'.$row['type_name']. '</label>';
                if($i%5==0)
                {
                 $i = 0;
                 echo '<br><br>';
                }
                $i++;}
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there are tons of jQuery validation plugins out there, but t his is pretty simple to do:

```
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
   if (!$(":checkbox:checked").length) {
      $("form").append("<div>Check at least one box please</div>");
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: Even though your solution will work; `.length` returns an integer and not a boolean. It's cleaner if you would do something like `if ($(":checkbox:checked").length > 0) {`
Keeps things readable and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.form').submit(function(){


    var checked = true ;

    $('.check_box').each(function(){

         if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {

             checked = false;   
         }

         if(!checked){

            $('.error_div').html("please select at least on check box");
            return false;
         }

    });       
});
```